# include() function in php is not working

Tags: php

i'm currently working on a website that has three folders namely admin,images and includes.
The includes section has the file 'connect.php' that tells about my database and the code for that is as follows..

```
<?php
 $db_username ="root";
 $db_password ="*****";
 $db_host ="localhost";
 $db_name= "ecommerce";

 $db=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name) or die("something went     
 wrong");
 if(!$db)
 {
    echo "failed".mysqli_error();
 }

echo "succesfull";

?>
```

i just want to include this file to "dum.php" which is present in the folder admin,for which i have written the includes function.here is the code for "dum.php"

```
<?php include_once('includes/connect.php');?>
```

so,when i'm running it on browser,it has to print either "an sql failure" or a "succesful" message. but it does neither of that?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Always enable error reporting when developing code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script. You would be seeing PHP complain about a non-existing file `includes/connect.php` because it's in a different directory.

Answer (score 2):

If `includes` is at the same level as `admin`, it should be:

```
include_once('../includes/connect.php');
```

You should probably use `require` instead of `include` so you get an error immediately if it fails.

Comment: what does same level here means? both of them are two folders present in a project called ecommerce

Comment: Your code looks for `includes` as a subdirectory of `admin`. Same level means that they're both subdirectories of the same parent.

Comment: Pathnames are interpreted relative to the directory of the current script. So if it's a sibling directory, you have to go up with `..` first, then go down into `includes`.

Comment: some people build everything directly off their base folder, so they just need to build up to the proper directory for everything.